# Attempt at parsing packets: Is there a Java equivalent to Python's "unpack"?

Tags: java, python

Is there an equivalent function to this Python function in Java?

[struct.unpack(fmt, string)](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html)

I'm trying to port a parser written in Python to Java, and I'm looking for a way to implement the following line of code:

```
handle, msgVer, source, startTime, dataFormat, sampleCount, sampleInterval, physDim,  digMin, digMax, physMin,  physMax,  freq, = unpack(self.headerFormat,self.unprocessed[pos:pos+calcsize(self.headerFormat)])
```

I'm using this in the context of a project where I receive bytes from the network and need to extract a specific part of the bytes to display them.

[EDIT 2]

The conclusion I had posted as an update was wrong.  I deleted it to avoid misleading others.

Comment: Does this help http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/FileWriter.html

Comment: Take look at Scanner - http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Nothing standard -- it can all be done "manually", of course, but I suspect a more automated solution is desired ;-)

Comment: @StasKurilin: Scanner parses text, not binary data.

Comment: @Inerdia - you can build it from InputStream.

Comment: @StasKurilin: I'd bet dollars to donuts that will just interpret the input stream with the platform-default encoding and still parse textual representations of primitive types rather than binary ones.

Comment: Are you talking about Java serialization?  http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/  Are 2 java programs going to be writing binary data to each other?

Comment: @Inerdia - You can easily specify encoding directly. Also I don't see actual difference between textual and binary representation in this case. Actual alternative to Scanner is to write analog that would use bit masks instead of regexp. But I would still try to do it with Scanner first.

Comment: @StasKurilin Exactly how do you read a native 4-byte integer from a binary stream using a Scanner?

Comment: @Inerdia - Yeah. I was wrong. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @pst How could I do that manually?  I'm really confused; I so far cast the individual bytes of my array to a String, but I can't figure out it's content.  I'm noob at this stuff, so if there's a manual method that would help me getting a better understanding, I would prefer using it than using a class that does it all for me.

I'm doing this as part of a school project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any real equivalent to Python's unpack in Java.

The conventional approach would be to read the data from a stream (originating either from a socket, or from a byte array read from the socket, via a ByteArrayInputStream) using a [DataInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html). That class has a set of methods for reading various primitives.

In your case, you would do something like:

```
DataInputStream in;
char[] handle = new char[6]; in.readFully(handle);
byte messageVersion = in.readByte();
byte source = in.readByte();
int startTime = in.readInt();
byte dataFormat = in.readByte();
byte sampleCount = in.readByte();
int sampleInterval = in.readInt();
short physDim = in.readShort();
int digMin = in.readInt();
int digMax = in.readInt();
float physMin = in.readFloat();
float physMax = in.readFloat();
int freq = in.readInt();
```

And then turn those variables into a suitable object.

Note that i've opted to pack each field into the smallest primitive which will hold it; that means putting unsigned values into signed types of the same size. You might prefer to put them in bigger types, so that they keep their sign (eg putting an unsigned short into an int); DataInputStream has a set of readUnsignedXXX() methods that you can use for that.