# Convert python's struct.unpack code to java

Tags: java, python

I am trying to integrate **Beuerer BF480** device with java program. I found python code which converts the received data through serial USB interface in the required format. Below is the code snippet which does the job in python:

```
frmt = "!" + "H"*64
x = struct.unpack(frmt, byte_array)
```

Could someone help me in understanding these 2 lines of code? If anyone knows java equivalent of this, it would be great to know.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempt at parsing packets: Is there a Java equivalent to Python's "unpack"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084836/attempt-at-parsing-packets-is-there-a-java-equivalent-to-pythons-unpack)

Comment: I have gone through the link provided by you prior to posting this question. This did not help me in writing the java equivalent of the code. It shows usage of handle variable. I am interested in the processing of headerFormat variable passed in 'unpack()'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question.

But, as I got it working for now, I would like to share the solution to this problem. Basically the python code is trying to convert byte array into Hexadecimal values. The expression `"!" + "H"*64` tells that its `BIG_ENDIAN` expression (start reading the byte array from the left) and convert bytes array into 64 Hex values.

I did not find the equivalent code in java which will do this job, but after struggling to decode the byte array I am able to get the intended results using below code.

```
public static int[] unpack(final byte[] byte_array) {
    final int[] integerReadings = new int[byte_array.length / 2];
    for(int counter = 0, integerCounter = 0; counter < byte_array.length;) {
        integerReadings[integerCounter] = convertTwoBytesToInteger(byte_array[counter], byte_array[counter + 1]);
        counter += 2;
        integerCounter++;
    }
    return integerReadings;
}

private static int convertTwoBytesToInteger(final byte byte1, final byte byte2) {
    final int unsignedInteger1 = getUnsignedInteger(byte1);
    final int unsignedInteger2 = getUnsignedInteger(byte2);
    return unsignedInteger1 * 256 + unsignedInteger2;
}

private static int getUnsignedInteger(final byte b) {
    int unsignedInteger = b;
    if(b < 0) {
        unsignedInteger = b + 256;
    }
    return unsignedInteger;
}
```

This code is about byte level manipulation of the data stream. However, it solves my problem as of now and I am getting the expected results. If there is a better solution to this, I would definitely like to implement the same.